# How to filter out each entry in a column, if each entry is a list, PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have this column called "content", every entry in this column is a list, i want to filter and modify "every list" in the column so that every element in a list is filtered out if it does not contain the word `car`, how can i do that with pandas?

I tried this, however it does actually filter anything when i save the data in the file, i am new to pandas ,so sometimes i get confused on how it works

```py
output['content'] = output['content'].apply(lambda x: 'car' in x)
```

each entry has a list, i am aiming to filter out that list, so that it only includes sentencs/string that has the word `car`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to remove entries from each list, which does not include word car, then you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.DataFrame({'content':[['car_one', 'car_two', 'airplane'],
                              ['car_three', 'car', 'train']]})
print(df)
df['content'] = df['content'].apply(lambda val: [x for x in val if 'car' in x.split()])
df.head()
```

Comment: I edited my question, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use a classical *listcomp* :

```
df["filtered_col"] = [[e for e in lst if "car" in e] for lst in df["col"]]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                                     col                      filtered_col
0                     [A first car, foo]                     [A first car]
1                  [baz, Almost a c a r]                                []
2  [car, A second car, baz, A third car]  [car, A second car, A third car]
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"col": [["A first car", "foo"],
             ["baz", "Almost a c a r"],
             ["car", "A second car", "baz", "A third car"]]}
)
```

Comment: really really slow for 6000 rows

Comment: Good luck with that because pandas is not designed to work with lists as elements of the dataframe/columns.

Comment: do you know any good tool for that?